# Edit hyperlink inside repeater using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to change Url of an asp hyperlink NavigateUrl inside Repeater control. I filled out my repeater from database using below code:

in .cs file

```
        SqlConnection con3 = new SqlConnection("my connection");
        string strcon = "select * from companydata";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(strcon, con3);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "company");
        Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
        con3.Close();
        con3.Dispose();
```

in .aspx file`<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"><ItemTemplate>
          <asp:HyperLink ID="companyid" runat="server"><%#Eval("companyname") %></asp:HyperLink> //i need to add NavigateUrl for HyperLink using loop.
                   </ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater>`

My output (using repeater) looking like this

- Microsoft
- Google
- Yahoo
- Facebook
- Adobe

Now i add some extra code to fill NavigateUrl in Hyperlink inside repeater control

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            HyperLink hplink = item.FindControl("companyid") as HyperLink;
            hplink.NavigateUrl = "https://www.example.com/company/"; 
        }
```

Now my question is how to add HyperLink's text inside NavigateUrl like www.example.com/company/Microsoft or www.example.com/company/Google, Here `Microsoft` and `Google` are link's text. Thanks in advance, sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to concat the text of hyperlink with the navigateurl:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        HyperLink hplink = item.FindControl("companyid") as HyperLink;
        hplink.NavigateUrl = "https://www.example.com/company/" + hplink.Text; 
    }
```

Comment: I already used hplink.Text but it's not working and return same link www.example.com/company/

Comment: Put a debug point at **hplink.NavigateUrl** and check the values of hplink. I am sure you will find the reason for not working or post the values you are able to see, so that i can help you